# sesiones en laravel

Tags: laravel

Tengo un inconveniente con mi proyecto.

he notado que cuando accedo a mi pagina desde otro lado que viene redireccionada ya sea desde facebook/instagram/wats

**ejemplo.com/login 
(Me sale el login, me pide mis credenciales) Y eso está mal. pues actualmente tengo una sesión abierta lo que debería de mandarme al home**

entonces me percate que al  introducir mis  credenciales (pero de otro usuario)

tomo dos sesiones en el mismo navegador diferente pestaña.

(entonces al hacer pruebas note de nuevo que si yo escribo manualmente )

ejemplo.com/login

me carga el home

pero si viene desde otro lado fb/tw/wats de donde sea. me carga el Login  :(

el link es exactamente igual

ejemplo.com/login <- Entonces copie y pegue ese link en otra pestaña y de nuevo me pide mis credenciales.

**En resumen : No toma la sesión actual si la pagina viene desde otro lado(pide de nuevo credenciales) cuando ya tengo una sesión**

Comment: Estas seguro que tienes tu Oauth2 de fb bien configurado? ademas, la configuración de la sesión de  laravel no se pierde por entrar en otra pestaña, a no ser que sea otro navegador, que uses http en una y https en otra, que limpiaras cache, que te desloguearas o que entres en incógnito.

Comment: inclusive hasta desactive lo de facebook. pero apenas me percate que si abro desde otro lado mi pagina .. simplemente me pide de nuevo las credenciales cuando ya tengo una sesión activa.

Comment: has revisado que te este guardando las sesiones normales? (olvidate del fb de momento)

Comment: me he olvidado de facebook es bastante raro .. que cuando abro la pagina desde messenger/wats o de algun otro lado me pide de nuevo que introduzca las credenciales :/